# .form-group to have the height of the element inside

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to set `border-right: 1px solid #2e2e2e` to a `.form-group` element, but it doesn't match the height of its content and it looks ugly.

Here's a demo:

```css
/* My styles */

.form-group {
  border-right: 1px solid #2e2e2e;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-toggle {
    padding: 15px 40px 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.11.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.11.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="selectpicker form-control">
      <option>Option #1</option>
      <option>Option #2</option>
      <option>Option #3</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="selectpicker form-control">
      <option>Option #1</option>
      <option>Option #2</option>
      <option>Option #3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Send</button>
</form>
```

**Edit**: Run it in `Full page mode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `height:auto;` to `.form-control`

Answer (score 0):

`float:left` of the child elements and fixed `height` of your `bootstrap-select` are causing this issue.

### Code Snippet

```css
/* My styles */

.form-group {
  border-right: 1px solid #2e2e2e;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-toggle {
  padding: 15px 40px 15px 0;
}
.mycustomform {} .mycustomform .btn-group {
  height: auto;
}
.mycustomform .form-group::before,
.mycustomform .btn-group::before {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.mycustomform {} .mycustomform .form-group::after,
.mycustomform .btn-group::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.11.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.11.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form class="form-inline mycustomform">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="selectpicker form-control">
      <option>Option #1</option>
      <option>Option #2</option>
      <option>Option #3</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="selectpicker form-control">
      <option>Option #1</option>
      <option>Option #2</option>
      <option>Option #3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below code, hope it works

```css
.form-group{
 border-right:1px solid #000;
 padding-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.11.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.11.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="selectpicker form-control">
      <option>Option #1</option>
      <option>Option #2</option>
      <option>Option #3</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="selectpicker form-control">
      <option>Option #1</option>
      <option>Option #2</option>
      <option>Option #3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Send</button>
</form>
```

***watch in big screen***

Answer (score 0):

set margin-bottom:15px; for the div inside .form-group

Answer (score 0):

No sure if this will help anyone, but I have run into issues where the `.form-group` class does not want to have a dynamic height. Adding `height: auto` to `.form-group` will fix this.